# sum of chromatic numbers

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

How I can prove that in given simple graph G in n vertices:
$$\chi(G) + \chi(\overline{G}) \leq n + 1.$$
Where $\chi$ is chromatic number.

I tried to do like that:

$$\chi(G) \leq \Delta(G) + 1 \;; \; (\Delta\text{ is max degree)}$$ 
$$\chi(\overline{G}) \leq \Delta(\overline{G}) + 1$$
$$\chi(G) + \chi(\overline{G}) \leq \Delta(G) + 1 + \Delta(\overline{G}) + 1$$
$$\Delta(G) + \Delta(\overline{G}) = n-1\;; \text{because graph is simple}$$
$$\chi(G) + \chi(\overline{G}) \leq n - 1 + 1 +  1$$
$$\chi(G) + \chi(\overline{G}) \leq n + 1$$
But I think I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you know anything about the relationship between largest independent set and chromatic number? Or the relationship between largest clique and chromatic number?

Comment: Also, $\Delta(G)+\Delta(\overline{G})$ is not, in general, $n-1$. Consider the graph given by a triangle and an isolated vertex. In this, $\Delta(G)=2$, $\Delta(\overline{G})=3$, and $n=4$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inequalities between chromatic number and the number of vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415795/inequalities-between-chromatic-number-and-the-number-of-vertices)